# How to get click event fired on disabled <b-form-input> in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, events, input, nuxt.js

I disabled `b-form-input` field. I need to enable it on input box click but @click does not work.

```
<b-form-input
    value="John"
    :disabled="!detailsEditable"
    @input="detailsEditable = true"
></b-form-input>
```

In script, initialize detailsEditable = false

Comment: A disabled element does not emit click events. You might want to add an invisible overlay over the disabled element, so that it can capture the click event.

Answer (score 1):

Set readonly for b-form-input

```
<b-form-input
    value="John"
    :readonly="!detailsEditable"
    @input="detailsEditable = true"
></b-form-input>
```